# Can I use pcs(pieces) as the quantity for ordering mugs?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

I like to ask the **mug** supplier if they take bulk order in around 300, can I say:

> Do you take bulk order in around 300/pcs?

Comment: They would likely understand it but why wouldn't you just say 300 mugs? Also if you are looking for a generic term perhaps units would be better than piece, which might be misconstrued as a part of a complete unit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

[The word **piece** is defined as](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piece)

> an amount that is cut or separated from a larger section of something

Which in this case, refers to a certain portion of their supply. You are simply asking for around 300 mugs out of their xxx mugs in supply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. "Mug" is a countable noun and it can be counted using the word 'piece'.

But please note that we do not commonly use the '/' sign before the 'pieces' because it might be read as "300 per piece". If you want to use 'per' it should be 'X per piece', where X is the price for every piece of the item, not the particular item you are buying.

So, based on your sentence, it's "Do you take bulk orders, say, 300 pieces [of mugs]?"

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

> Do you take bulk *orders for* around **300 pieces**?

You wouldn't use the "/" acts as a "per", as in:

> I heard that they cost $10.00/100 pieces.

And I don't think there is any need to use an abbreviation unless the full word is repetitively used.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of *units* that are possible. Aside from the fact that the definition works, it seems to be used as well.

[image]